# Can you use JAXX with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, frameworks

I'm wanting to style Swing components with CSS and saw this as my best bet. But I'm having a bit of a problem just finding out if I can use it with Eclipse?

Is it also practical for a medium sized project, or should I be looking for another way to style components?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Document for your answer

https://docs.google.com/document/d/19bYF0z5sNiwT-zL5VAZBY1CM0MgHA6pqzZ8dP22llvc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on a subject of Swing and especially JAXX, but I know a thing or two about Eclipse. If this question is still relevant, you can take my answer as a basis to do some more research.

I searched an [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/JAXX) and googled a bit but found nothing about JAXX Eclipse support or plugins. If you know french you can check project's documentation. If there is nothing about tool support in the documentation, I suggest you ask the creators directly.

Eclipse gives you some tools you can use to work with file types JAXX uses. From what I have read [here](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/03/30/introducing-jaxx.html), *.jaxx files are just XML files and stylesheets are just a CSS. I suggest you install XML and CSS support through Eclipse Web Tools Platform and associate *.jaxx files with XML editor either when you first open one of the files with such extension or through [File Associations Preferences](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-13.htm). In order to compile *.jaxx files you can configure Eclipse Project Builder or use an External Tools launcher.

By the way, have you considered using JavaFX?

Answer (score 0):

**[@duemir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/191103/duemir)**

I have mentioned same thing in my Answer Document.

Please check the Above answer by Me (Jugal Thakkar)

**OR**

[Click on this Link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/19bYF0z5sNiwT-zL5VAZBY1CM0MgHA6pqzZ8dP22llvc/edit?usp=sharing)

Go to your Link and Check the **Resource** in that page and try to go Official Website of JAXX.
You are not able to Go on Official Project Page (www.jaxxframework.org/).
**I have mentioned all things in My Document** so please first go through that.

**I can conclude that on This Question**.

1) **This Project is not Officially Working**. because you can't open official Project Website.
   so you are not able to access docs and other stuff.